# Recursively remove same files found with locate

Tags: command-line, find, rm, locate

It seems this question has been asked in a number of ways. But I would like to use `rm` instead of `find`.

I followed a number of explanations as to how to use `find`, but I'm having an issue with executing the `find` command. When I use locate I get the following output:

```
maxgitt@mgpc:/etc$ locate omero
/etc/nginx/conf.d/omeroweb.conf
/etc/rc0.d/K01omero-web
/etc/rc1.d/K01omero-web
/etc/rc2.d/S03omero-web
/etc/rc3.d/S03omero-web
/etc/rc4.d/S03omero-web
/etc/rc5.d/S03omero-web
/etc/rc6.d/K01omero-web
```

But then when I try to use find to delete the respective files, I get the following error.

```
maxgitt@mgpc:/etc$ find -type f -name '*omero*'
./etc/rc0.d/K01omero-web
./etc/rc1.d/K01omero-web
./etc/rc2.d/S03omero-web
./etc/rc3.d/S03omero-web
./etc/rc4.d/S03omero-web
./etc/rc5.d/S03omero-web
./etc/rc6.d/K01omero-web
find: ‘./cups/ssl’: Permission denied
find: ‘./ppp/peers’: Permission denied
find: ‘./polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘./ssl/private’: Permission denied
./nginx/conf.d/omeroweb.conf
find: ‘./chatscripts’: Permission denied
find: ‘./docker’: Permission denied
```

So I opted instead to use the command:

```
maxgitt@mgpc:/etc$ sudo rm -rf /etc/*/*omero-web*
```

But I'd prefer to be able to remove all files within the `etc/` directory and its respective subdirectories. I am left with one file because of my hacky `rm` command:

```
maxgitt@mgpc:/etc$ locate omero
/etc/nginx/conf.d/omeroweb.conf
```

Comment: Please simple run `sudo find -type f -name '*omero*'` and error will go away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sudo

And always do a dry run before deleting to ensure you are not removing more than bargained for.

```
sudo find -type f -name '*omero*'
```

Then, assuming list looks good

```
    sudo find -type f -name '*omero*' -delete
```

or specify a location to search (you already know these files are in /etc)

```
sudo find /etc -iname '*omero*' -delete
```

-delete is faster than `-exec rm {} \;` or `-print0 | xargs -0 rm` as it does not have to spawn another process.

EDIT: From the comments

```
for i in $(locate omero) ; do rm $i ; done
```

Comment: I should be more clear. The dry run DOES NOT LOOK GOOD. I don't want to remove the extra packages that `find` finds that `locate` did not find.

Comment: +1 to dry run. Hard to say without seeing the output and what you do and do not want to remove, I am guessing pass the location /etc , but just a guess. Update your question or use a loop `for i in $(locate locate omero)` ....

Comment: I am a little confused. I would infact like to remove everything that `locate` shows me but not the extra files that are found by `found` as shown above I would not like to remove. Is there a way to remove the files found only through locate

Comment: Look at bash loops http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html . `for i in $(locate omero) ; do rm $i ; done` . Can have problems with spaces in file names, etc, but should suffice. OR refine your find either by refining the search parameters or search path, hard to tell from what little you have posted.

Comment: ^ this was the true answer

Comment: How about `rm -i` instead? When messing with files outside the home directory one cannot be careful enough… With `find`, `-delete` is the fast and mercyless and `-exec rm -i {} +` the just a little bit slower but safer way.

Comment: @dessert - I suppose you missed the "dry run" part of my answer. "And always do a dry run before deleting to ensure you are not removing more than bargained for"

Comment: `locate` can do null-terminated output, so instead of `for i in $(locate ...)`; `locate -0 ... | xargs -0 ...` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the `sudo` to your command:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -name '*omero*' -delete
```

and the error will go away. Reason being that those files are owned by `root user` and can only be remove by those in the `sudo` group and root user.

Comment: Well, technically can only be removed by root and users in the sudo group can run the command as root. The command will not work without sudo even if you are in the sudo group.

Answer (score 1):

There are many many reasons to use find rather than rm. Especially if your version of find supports the "-delete" option:

- If your filenames contain spaces or newlines, your `rm` command will not work and may even delete the wrong files.
- If there are a lot of files to delete, the command will fail for exceeding the maximum command line length.

If your find supports "-delete":

```
find -type f -path "*omero*" -delete
```

If your find does not support "-delete" and requires a starting path:

```
find . -type f -path "*omero*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

That '`-print0` ... `-0`' is important. This tells find to output filenames delimited by NUL, and xargs -0 will expect NUL delimited filenames. This way spaces and newlines in your filenames won't cause problems.

Also, I'm using `-path` instead of `-name` to more closely match what "locate" gives you. However, this means that a file will be deleted if it happens to be underneath a directory with "omero" in it. This is probably not what you want, and you should use `-name` instead.

With that out of the way, if you're sure of what you got in the end, put `sudo` at the front of the first version. Or `sudo` at the front of both `find` and `xargs` in the second.

Comment: How about `-exec rm -i {} +`? I think it's a good idea to ask for every file before deleting it here…

Comment: @dessert I did not know about the `{} +` variation! Thank you!